# Tool to check if all website pages are working without error in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, testing, deployment, azure

Presently i am working on a website it has around 50 pages and links. I need to make sure that all the pages are running fine before deploying to production. Is there any tool so that i can check on local machine that no page is displaying an error message of any kind.

Note:- i am making website using ASP.Net, SQL Azure, Window Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this - http://www.relsoftware.com/wlv/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure what do you want to check. If it's related with your business logic you have to check by yourself, or by some unit test framework. For windows azure deployment verification, I would like to recommend you to do as below:

1, Since you said you are using Windows Azure and SQL Azure, please have two server for testing. One to simulate the windows azure environment, installed Win08 x64 (R2 if you are using Azure OS 2.x), .NET Fx 4.0 (or 3.5.1 if you are using 3.5 SP1), Windows Azure SDK, IIS with URL rewrite. Do NOT anything else on this machine, for example VS, Win SDK etc. On another machine to simulator SQL Azure, just install SQL Server 08 R2.

2, Deploy your azure application on the first machine using CSPack, CSRUN, etc. and connect to the SQL Server on the other machine, test your application. If you are using storage service, firstly using the local emulator on the first machine.

3, Change to use real azure storage and test.

4, Change to use real SQL Azure and test.

5, Deploy your application on azure staging slot and test.

6, Swap to production slot.

In SDK 1.5 and later the Azure VS Tool have a feature to help you to verify if there's any assemblies you referenced in your project are missing on azure VM. So you can set them as Copy Local = True. There's also a website help you to verify the assemblies http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on what errors you might want to check, but if you just only want to check for broken links then there is a tool called Xenu that could help you. It will traverse all of the links and send back nice HTML reports on the broken links.

Answer (score 0):

Would ELMHA help here?

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Check out Wades post for Azure usage: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-with-table-storage/